# Exit windows batch script gracefully?

Tags: windows, command-line, path, batch-file

My `PATH` is too full, so I need to put things in batch scripts like "cl.bat":

```bsh
@echo off
%comspec% /k ""%ProgramFiles%\MICROS~1.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""
call cl %*
```

Unfortunately this has a side effect keeping the script running in the background.

Note: I have also tried `start cl %*`, `open cl %*` and `cl %*`.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for my Visual Studio 2012 Express:

```
@echo off
setlocal

call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
start "CL" /B cl.exe %*

endlocal
```

This will spawn an independent process and continue without wait.
`vsvars32.bat` must not be started in a sub-shell.
Otherwise, the adjustments of the environment won't survive the call

Comment: That didn't work, and when I added a similar line above it I got a large number of command prompt windows spawning. By not working I mean it doesn't give me a working `cl` command.

Comment: Try the revised script. Note that you have double double-quotes in your original script.

Comment: Unfortunately that also didn't work. Running the commands manually on C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.60610.1 and it works, but not with the bat script.

Comment: Okay, based on your new edits there are no longer side-affects; however it (`cl`) doesn't produce any output.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The new version (see above) finally should work. Parameter /B prevents start to open a new window.

Comment: Okay, that is mostly working. With `VsDevCmd` it gives me no error and works, but doesn't exit once it's finishing compiling+linking the source. `vsvars32` just gives an error.